# Dynamic CRM 'PERCEIVED_RIBBON_KEY' is undefined

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When opening a popup for add/edit an Entity, got JS error in IE7 or +.

'PERCEIVED_RIBBON_KEY' is undefined

Any Idea why this issue raise on the IE not on other browsers.

Comment: Look like a javascript error. Have you recently installed any Rollup?

Answer (score 0):

Is this CRM Online? If so IE7 is no longer supported and you shouldn't expect it to work, IE7 is 6 years old.

[Browser compatibility introduced with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 12 or the December 2012 Service Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784954)